# JQuery accesses only the first item in the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI, and what i am doing is refreshing the charts by class so that i can refresh all charts without accessing each one by ID.
this is the code:

`$(".k-chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();`

The problem is that only the first chart having the class `k-chart`, gets refreshed whereas others are not affected.
Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about `$(".k-chart").each(function() {$(this).data("kendoChart").refresh(); });` - it may be the plugin is only expecting an id so only does the first item - not sure though as I haven't looked at it

Comment: @jafaar Did you use `this.data` instead of `$(this).data`?

Comment: @NotABlueWhale i actually tried the .each method, but my error was that i used `this.data` instead of `$(this).data` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.data` function will return the value only from the first matched item. If you need to call this method (and the subsequent `refresh` method) you'll need to iterate all the matched elements

```
$('.k-chart').each(function(){
    $(this).data('kendoChart').refresh();
});
```